# Duplicate tags [FosElasticaBundle] and [FosElasticBundle]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

In StackOverflow there are two tags [foselasticabundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foselasticabundle) and [foselasticbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foselasticbundle). The second one is a wrong duplicate of the first.

Am I allowed to fix that, and if yes, how?

Comment: [meta-tag:synonym-request]

Comment: Is that just a typo, or are there really two different names that mean the same thing?

Comment: @BilltheLizard "FOSElasticBundle" has 10100 results on Google while *"FOSElasticBundle"* only has 285. I'm gonna go with typo.

Comment: @Stijn you made a typo yourself in your comment, writing twice the same name :-) Anyway I can confirm it's a type, the correct name is FosElasticaBundle (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle)

Comment: @FrancescoAbeni copy-paste error, heh.

Comment: I just commented on @rene's answer wondering if `fos-elastica-bundle` would be a better tag name? Looks less like randomly smashed together letters and emphasises the *elastica* part... could even syn non-hyphenated to hyphenated...

Comment: @Stijn In that case we probably just need a retag, not a synonym. I agree with Jon that a hyphenated version would probably be better.

Comment: Ugh... there's also: `fosuserbundle`, `fosrestbundle`, `fosoauthserverbundle`, `fosfacebookbundle`, `foscommentbundle`- mine eyes - they bleed!

Comment: @JonClements those are the actual package names, so I think it makes sense to have corresponding tags. E.g. it would be weird to use `word-press` or `net-beans` or similar.

Comment: @FrancescoAbeni fair 'nuff. They'd still be identifiable as the package names but at least readable if hyphenated... I'm not fussed either way tbh - just throwing it out there as an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I retagged the 13 or so questions to [foselasticabundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foselasticabundle) which leaves 0 questions tagged with [foselasticbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foselasticbundle).

That zombie-tag will be removed by the script that normally runs at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: Wonder if `fos-elastica-bundle` is better... looks less randomly like letters bashed together and hopefully avoid any typos...

Comment: That is up to you or the OP @JonClements. Or do you want me to retag all those questions ... ;)